Principled BSDF Changes between 3.3 and 4.2
At work, we've been using Blender 3.3 LTS and since this LTS has come to an end, we are testing the next LTS (4.2).
Is it normal that a file saved in 3.3 looks very different when rendered in 4.2 (same change in 4.0)?
I've read the changelogs and saw updates on the Principled BSDF, but I thought the difference would be less visible than the image below.
Or is there an option to get the same result?
The scene has just 3 spheres, each with a different material between top and bottom ones, and the environment is gray.



There is a video that dives deeper in explanation. I recommend you to watch
https://youtu.be/v6qXbV_Q7z4?si=LDks2qdmbeWVWPY3

It's kind hard to tell with so little contrast or color. Yes looks different because the Principled changed, I don't think you can obtain a 1:1 equivalent without tweaking the shaders.

Blender 4.2 comes with Eevee-Next renderer which is quite different from the older version. This situation is similar to when Eevee, which first appeared in Blender 2.80, replaced the older viewport system altogether. Unfortunately, this also means that you might require to make modifications in your assets.
